# Time variable to timeout if condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following Python code that has an `if` condition that checks to see if `current_ident` is the same as last `ident` and if so then not print the `current_ident` value.

What I would like to do is add a time-out to this check so only check to see if the current and last is the same for 7 seconds after that let it print if it's the same. I'm thinking possible by adding a global variable `last_read` which saves the time and then maybe use something like `last_read + [timeout] > [current_time]`?

```
from nfc import ContactlessFrontend
from time import sleep

ident = '' 

def connected(tag):
    global ident
    current_ident = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in tag.identifier)
    if current_ident != ident:
        print(current_ident)
        ident = current_ident
    return False

clf = ContactlessFrontend('usb')
while True:
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': connected})
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You could use ```time.sleep(7)```. This pauses the execution for 7 seconds.

Comment: So how often does `connected()` get called?

Comment: @quamrana connected() gets called everytime a NFC tag is touched the the NFC USB Reader. The code is to prevent processing the same tag twice accidently if someone was holding the NFC tag down. But then if I have a timeout then there is a chance that it's not accidental holding down

Comment: @martineau any chance you can show me a snippet code example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to keep a track of time as well as the last ident:

```py
from nfc import ContactlessFrontend
from time import sleep
import time

ident = '' 
next_time = None

def connected(tag):
    global ident
    global next_time
    current_ident = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in tag.identifier)
    if current_ident != ident:
        next_time = time.time() + 7
        print(current_ident)  # Brand new ident
        ident = current_ident
    elif time.time() > next_time:
        next_time = time.time() + 7
        print(current_ident)  # Repeated ident allowed
    # else:  # disallow repeated ident
    return False

clf = ContactlessFrontend('usb')
while True:
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': connected})
    sleep(1)
```